# How do I get rid of this, hopefully forever?

Tags: firefox, bing

OS - Windows 8, 8.1 & 10
browser - Firefox

I am unsure which company created the small overlay window & I've asked Microsoft, Firefox & Bing about this, never got an answer from them.

When I go to Bing.com & then click on videos there is a small window/overlay on the left hand side of the screen at the bottom:

[image: !Playlist]

How do I get rid of this, so I never see it again?

Comment: You've not told us whether it happens with other browsers.

Comment: Are you signed in to Bing? What happens if you sign out?

Comment: When I used internet explorer it is there also. Now I only use Firefox.

Comment: I sign in to my windows account & nothing else. I do/am not signed into bing , Google or Firefox.

Comment: Will signing in to Bing give me a way to remove it forever?

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://www.bing.com/saves?type=Videos then click on [image: Manage], then [image: Select all] and finally [image: Delete]

Make sure that you never add a video to your playlist again by avoiding

[image: Add to saved videos]

Comment: Thank you, that removed the 2 videos I had saved there. It did not prevent the darn thing from showing up the next time I look for videos.

Comment: I want to never see it or use it ever again.

Comment: Then I suggest you don't use Bing but an alternative search engine instead. You can hardly influence the content of the website made by Microsoft.